# Regex to select text X if it finds text Y

Tags: c#, regex

**Description**

I need a regex expression to match everything in the "value" of a key/value entry of an xml file if it finds a certain text within that line.

**Problem**

For the example test string:

```
<add key="myDatabase" value="Server=abc-lsatdm094\devbox1;Database=myDB;User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;" />
```

I need to match everything in value:

```
Server=abc-lsatdm094\devbox1;Database=myDB;User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;
```

**IF** and only if the line contains "mydb"

**My Regex Expression Attempts**

- `(?<=(Server=)|(Data Source=))[^;]*`
- `.*(D|d)atabase=(M|m)(Y|y)(D|d)(B|b).*`

**Additional Test Strings**

```
<add key="myDatabase" value="Data Source=abc-lsatdm094\devbox1;Database=myDB;User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;" />
<add key="myDatabase" value="User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;Data Source=abc-lsatdm094\devbox1;Database=mydb;" />
<add key="myDatabase-DatabaseConnectionString" value="Server=abc-lsatdm094\devbox1;Database=myDB;User Id=xxxxxx;Password=xxxxxx;" />
<add key="myDatabase-DatabaseConnectionString" value="Data Source=$LocalInstance; database=myDb; Trusted_Connection=True;" />
<add key="myDatabase-databaseConnectionString" value="database=mydb; Trusted_Connection=True;Data Source=$LocalInstance;" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found a solution to this as I was about to post:

`(?<=value=").*(M|m)(Y|y)(D|d)(B|b).*;`

**Breakdown**

`(?<=value=")`

This portion is the "look behind".  So the text must contain `value="`  This is "matched" but not included in the capture group.

`.*`

This says to match all (for now)

`(M|m)(Y|y)(D|d)(B|b)`

This says to match `mydb` (uppercase and lowercase)

`.*;`

and continue capturing until the last instance of `;`

Comment: It would be great if you could explain the regex in your solution for others with similar problems

Comment: This approach is wrong because there's no proof that `value="` and `myDB` belong to the same tag.