# If a string contains word X, select only word Y

Tags: c#, regex

i had a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37416721/regex-to-select-text-x-if-it-finds-text-y) that I was able to solve.

What I need is if a string contains word X, select only word Y.

I want to be able to say, if this string contains "azureStorage", then select, "mystorage"

```
<add name="azureStorage" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=mystorage;AccountKey=myKey" />
```

The closest thing I have is this regex, which works on regex101 but not in c#.

```
(?<=(azureStorage)...................................................AccountName=).[^;]*
```

Clearly this is not a good solution.

[Here is a link to the example on Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/rX5qQ0/1)

Comment: Why use regex101 if you need a .NET regex? The regex101 does not support .NET syntax and features. Test at regexhero.net or regexstorm.net.

Comment: Instead of using regular expressions, why not parse the XML and then parse the connection string?

Comment: Why not use `azureStorage.*AccountName=([^;]*)` and grab captured group #1

Comment: Related: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/216074)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict the lookbehind to just the string `azureStorage`, and then grab anything after `AccountName=` that's not `;`:

```
(?<=azureStorage).*AccountName=([^;]+)
```

You may want to add a word boundary check at the end, in case the `AccountName` is the last component of the connection string:

```
(?<=azureStorage).*AccountName=([^;]+)\b
```

Comment: This along with the @anubhava 's answer and just accessing the captured group work for me.  juharr had a good answer for parsing XML, but the xml string i posted was just an example and I wanted to know how to do this for any text.  Thanks.